# Iterate through stdClass

Tags: php, arrays

How on Earth do I get the ids, and names from this array (possibly by using a ForEach construct)?

```
stdClass Object (
 [data] => Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Corinne Culbard [id] => 5005561918 ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Tom West [id] => 5034297044 ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Sabri Tasci [id] => 5057373639 )
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which sections of the PHP manual did you read that looked relevant but which did not help you or which you did not fully understand?

Comment: The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) is so awesome that 90% of the time your answer has already been posted in the user comments. It's also a great place to find alternative syntax, issues and workarounds with tons of examples. It should be your first port of call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this not working?

```
foreach ($object->data as $item) {
    $name = $item->name;
    $id = $item->id;
}
```